# Understand package imports

Tags: python

I have started learning python very recently. I do have a typescript and C# background. I was trying to understand the packages and imports statements. Following is the very basic folder structure I have created and I have few questions on this

```
app/
 |-> pkg1/
      |-> fib.py
      |-> __init__.py
 |- >pkg2/
      |-> mul.py
      |-> __init__.py
 |-> app.py
ext/
 |-> ext.py
 |-> __init__.py 

fib.py
------
from pkg2.mul import mul
// from ..pkg2.mul import mul -> Error: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
// but this should work as per docs https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references
// can someone tell why do I get this error?

def fib(n):
    return mul(n) * 2

mul.py
------
def mul(n):
    return n * 10

app.py
------
from pkg1.fib import fib
print(fib(1))
```

I have read Python treats any file as entry file.

- Does python even know `app.py` is the entry point? No I guess.
- Why does it work when I have given `pkg2.mul` in `fib.py`
- Why does it work when I have given `pkg1.fib` in `app.py`
- What if I want to include `ext.py` inside `mul.py` and `app.py`
- As per folder structure, if `app.py` imports `pkg1.fib` (relative to `app.py`) is valid then `fib.py` must import `mul` in different way correct? why it is working for `pkg2.mul`? Is it actually Valid? `pkg2/` is not relative to `fib.py`.

Am I missing something? In typescript we use relative imports and C# we use namespaces and include files but here I am pretty confused. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This may help you for a high level [Python Package](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/package) but this may help you use the basics [An Introduction to Python Packages for Absolute Beginners](https://hackernoon.com/pip-install-abra-cadabra-or-python-packages-for-beginners-33a989834975)

Comment: Looks like you might be missing an `__init__.py` in your `app/` directory

Comment: @Hoog Do I need __init__.py in app/ because it is where my main script exists. I think __init__.py is needed if you want to make it as package.I dont think we need to make it a package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your relative import attempt did not work because `pkg1` and `pkg2` are *separate packages*. Relative imports only work within one package.

> Does python even know `app.py` is the entry point?

No. It's just some .py file sitting around in a directory.

> Why does it work when I have given `pkg2.mul` in `fib.py`

Coincidence. You are in the `app/` directory, and the first element of `sys.path` is the working directory. It likely won't work if you cd to some other directory.

> Why does it work when I have given `pkg1.fib` in `app.py`

Same as above.

> What if I want to include `ext.py` inside `mul.py` and `app.py`

You have to package `ext` and include it as a dependency of `app`.

> As per folder structure, if `app.py` imports `pkg1.fib` (relative to `app.py`) is valid then `fib.py` must import `mul` in different way correct? Why it is working for `pkg2.mul`?  Is it actually valid? `pkg2/` is not relative to `fib.py`.

It's not importing relative to `app.py`. They are both importing from cwd (check the first element of `sys.path` displayed by using `python -m site`)

Comment: Can you please explain this statement in detail **You have to package ext and include it as a dependency of app.** or any reference helps as well

Comment: I'm assuming "ext" is short for "an external dependency". Best practice would be to maintain that source code in an entirely separate directory/project. Any packages that want to `import ext` and use that as a library should have the dependency specified in their metadata (you can mention it in `install_requires` of the `setup.py`)

Answer (score 0):

The basic issue is that your `app` is not package (because it is missing an `__init__.py` file) which means when you go two levels up to the `app` directory you aren't in a package any more, and thus the error stating that you are attempting to import beyond the top-level package.

See [this section on intra-package references](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references) for more info on how you could restructure your package to allow what you are attempting to do. You also check out [this section explaining the module search path](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path) for a little more context.